# How to use XMLHttpRequest to return a file in Firefox? Never seems to hit readystate == 4 and status == 200

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, xmlhttprequest

Basically I am using Ajax to call a C# WebMethod that returns a byte array that consists of an excel file. It is working in IE and Chrome but does not work in Firefox. The console is returning a `readystate` of 4 but a status of 0 in FireFox whereas in the other browsers it is getting into the if block where `readystate` is 4 and status is 200. Below is the code.  If anyone knows what I am doing wrong, I would greatly appreciate the assistance but I have tried a bunch of steps to remedy the situation and none of them have been working.

If I put in an `alert('got here')` after the line containing `xhttp.send`, will it work in Firefox?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("#operation").click(function () {
        var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhttp.open("POST", "Default.aspx/GetText");
        xhttp.addEventListener("progress", function (e) {
            if (e.lengthComputable) {
                //alert("TOTAL:" + e.total + " LOADED:" + e.loaded);

                var percentComplete = Math.ceil((e.loaded / e.total) * 100);
                progressBar.max = e.total;
                progressBar.val(percentComplete);

                //console.log(percentComplete);
            }
        }, false);
        xhttp.responseType = 'blob';
        xhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
        xhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
            var a;
            //console.log(xhttp);
            if (xhttp.readyState === 4 && xhttp.status === 200) {
                var blob = xhttp.response;
                var link = document.createElement('a');
                link.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
                link.download = "ItemMatrix.xlsx";
                document.body.appendChild(link);
                link.click();
            } else {
                console.log(xhttp);
            }
        };
        xhttp.send(JSON.stringify({ sender: 'Generate Excel', itemLIST: $('#MainContent_itemnumberlist').val(), includeIMAGES: $('#<%= IncludeImages.ClientID %>').is(':checked') }));
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Why don't you use jQuery to do your ajax call?

Comment: @MarkBaijens there are better alternatives to jQuery now, especially for one-off use cases, like ajax calls (e.g. [axios](https://www.npmjs.com/package/axios)).

Comment: @General_Twyckenham Let everyone use the library that they want. What is good and what is bad is a matter of opinion. The OP already uses jQuery but not for the ajax call. Also the questions is tagged with jQuery. That's the reason for my question.

Comment: @MarkBaijens Your 2nd & 3rd points are fair; 1st point is less so. The modern web is increasingly bloated with unnecessary Javascript; including all of jQuery just for ajax is a waste.

Comment: @General_Twyckenham Where did you read jQuery is only used by the OP for a ajax call? (it even isn't) You have only seen this small snippet which is probably only a fraction of the total code in his project.

Comment: The reason why i didn't use jquery with XMLHttpRequest is because I just found this example using regular javascript and it worked so that is what I went with.

Comment: @blk99cobra Since you already using the jQuery library I recommend you to have a look at http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/. jQuery can do ajax calls easier then plain javascript and takes away some specific browser logic. It might not solve your problem but your code will be easier to maintain.

Comment: @MarkBaijens The only information about the project is what OP posted, and I didn't look closely at the code. As such, I'm not going to recommend pulling in a large multi-purpose library that someone may not already be using if good alternatives exist. That being said, since OP is already using jQuery, I'd agree that he should use it for this purpose

Comment: @General_Twyckenham He already uses jQuery. The question is tagged with jQuery and you can see the use of jQuery binding to a click event. No extra library is needed to do ajax calls with jQuery.

Comment: @MarkBaijens that's what I just said. As far as the question being tagged with jQuery, I've seen far too many mistagged questions to use that as a strong indicator

Comment: I read other examples of people using jquery with XMLHttpRequest or jquery's jqxhr object and having issues with getting the file to be saved from the byte array that is being returned; hence, is why I went with use plain old javascript.  My question isn't should I use jquery for this or regular javascript, it is why is this not working in Firefox but works in IE and Chrome yet when I put in an alert after the send, then it will work in Firefox.

Comment: @General_Twyckenham last thing I gonna say about it. Let people make there own choices of technology they use. Stack overflow is not a platform for opinion based topics. There are other sites for that.

Comment: @MarkBaijens You seem to completely miss the point, but there's not much I can do about it at this point. Good luck

Comment: @blk99cobra Do you have any console messages. Could be something CORS related. You could check the http messages to for difference in headers too.

Comment: @MarkBaijens if it was CORS related, wouldn't I be seeing the same issue then in IE and Chrome?  I'm not that familiar with CORS to be honest.